# Cannot see devices on my home network when using my public IP

Tags: networking, router, ip

My ISP set me up with a public IP address a few years ago so it would be easier for me to connect to devices on my home network from my office. I just had to set up port forwarding rules on my home router, and everything worked fine. My home router gets a private IP address (let's call it `privateIP`) from my ISP's router in the building, and then they set up a 1:1 NAT on their router, mapping all ports from `privateIP` to my home router.

A few weeks ago, my home router failed, so I got a new one (a [TP Link Archer A7](https://www.tp-link.com/us/home-networking/wifi-router/archer-a7/)). I assumed that I could just set up the same port forwarding rules on the new one and everything would work just fine, and it ***does*** from ***outside*** my home network.

When I'm at home, however, I can't do anything with `publicIP`. I can't ping it from inside my network, or connect to any device via SSH or HTTP, and I ***can*** do both of those things from my office. With my old router (an [Asus RT-N56U](https://www.asus.com/us/SupportOnly/RT-N56U/HelpDesk_Knowledge/)), everything worked as expected when I used `publicIP`, whether I was connecting from my own subnet or from the outside.

My ISP claims that nothing on their side is different, and suggested that the default routing rules are different between my old router & my new one. That's as much as they can tell me, and I'm not terribly clear on how to set up a static route for this case. By that I mean, I know how to do it in my router's configuration, but I don't know what to set as the destination IP, subnet mask, and gateway in the routing table. In this case, I would think that the destination would specifically be `publicIP`, so the subnet would be `255.255.255.255`, but that feels wrong. Also, I have no idea what the gateway address should be for that.

Does this sound like I'm on the right track? How should I set up a route to the public IP address of my router from behind two NATs?

## Edit:

My home router's configuration (by default):
[image: Home router "advanced routing" configuration]

Note: the ISP's router in the building gives my home router an address on the 10.11.180.0/22 subnet (`privateIP`). That router is where the 1:1 NAT from `publicIP` to the 10.11.xxx.yyy address is configured. I don't have any control over that configuration, but it did work previously. My home router manages the 192.168.0.0/24 subnet.

Comment: "I would think that the destination would specifically be public IP Address" - This is indeed wrong.  Can you be more specific about what the rules look like currently. Since intranet IP addresses are non-unique, you should be able to use the actual addresses you are using, this will help us diagnose the your issue.  You can provide this information as an [edit] to your question.

Comment: at a glance, it seems like your new router does not support (or has not enabled) hairpin NAT.  Hairpinning is not common among home/soho grade routers, but is necessary if you wish to access a LAN device from within the LAN, using a target IP on the WAN side of the router.

Comment: It sounds a bit like _the ISP's_ CGNAT router isn't doing hairpin NAT anymore, or something along those lines... It's not particularly surprising that it doesn't work now; I'm a bit more curious about _how it worked before_, as that might be important in trying to replicate it. (For example, I'm not sure whether it's just 1:1 NAT or something more than that. There could have been setups where "the destination would specifically be publicIP, so the subnet would be 255.255.255.255" would be correct, although more likely not.)

Comment: The terminology here helps. Some searching with the term "hairpinning" lead to this "canonical answer:" https://serverfault.com/a/557776/421937

Comment: Personally I think the best way to address this issue would be to use "split-horizon DNS" as suggested in your linked answer. a raspberry pi running bind as a dns server is pretty cheap and easy to set up. then you can use names instead of IPs and resolve them equally on both networks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

External IP address is used in communication with the outside world. Inside our own network you use internal IP address. As the connections from your office work, there's nothing wrong with the routing.

For example; I have a Linux server I manage with SSH. The internal IP address of the server is 192.168.1.100/24. When I connect to it from the office, I'll go ssh user@externalip. When I connect to it at home from my workstation I'm in the same network, so I use the internal IP of the server instead, i.e. ssh user@192.168.1.100.

Only the traffic that's crossing the internet interface of your router will be routed. Traffic that's flowing inside the network does not cross this interface, so it's not routed but the router uses its switch part to forward the traffic using just the MAC addresses. Because the internal traffic never passes the internet interface you don't need to use the external IP address in intra-network communication at all.

Also because the traffic isn't routed, you don't have to set up any kind of static routes to reach the internal devices from other internal devices.

Please note: this assumes that all your internal devices are in the same network, as is by default the case with any off-the-shelf So-Ho router. If you have configured two or more separate VLANs and networks, the traffic between them *is* routed, and in some (rare) situations you might need to configure static routes. However because the traffic still isn't crossing the internet interface, you wouldn't use the external IP, only internal ones.

Some special cases may require using the external IP also with internal communications. There's no standardization that states how exactly a SoHo router must internally work, the device manufacturers have free hands in deciding what they offer. For example in this case it seems that the new router doesn't support hairpin NAT (NAT loopback) as Frank Thomas suggested in his comment above.

If the exact same functionality is required, the old device should be replaced with the same exact model; but even that case there may be a OS (firmware) difference between the old and new one causing difference in behavior. The only way to be certain is to compare the capabilities of the two devices (or OS versions) before purchase.

If the same or comparable device isn't readily found, one can check whether some Open Source router OS like OpenWRT has the required capability, and purchase a device that supports the replacement OS.

Comment: In principle, yes, I can simply use the device's NAT IP address when I'm on my home network. However, for a variety of reasons, I do still need to use the external IP address. Since it used to work with the old router, I know it CAN work, so I need to get back to the same state.

Comment: In the situation I'm talking about, NAT isn't in the picture at all. Only internal IPs. I don't doubt you need to use the external IP even with internal communications. But you did change the router, and as your ISP says the internals of the new router may well be different than the old one; see Frank's comment above. There's no standard stating how a SoHo router must internally work, so no guarantee what works on device A will work on device B. If you need the exact same functionality, you need to replace with the exact same device. Even then FW difference may change the behavior.

Comment: That's reasonable. Unfortunate, but reasonable. I had the foresight to get a router supported by OpenWRT, so I supposed I can give that a shot if it comes to it.

Comment: Yeah, OpenWRT seems to support NAT Loopback. Thanks for the comments, I updated my answer accordingly.